# How to optimize canvas particle system with particle objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

so I made a simple particle system with canvas and javascript (some jQuery) but I can't seem to make it run at more than 8fps on my old computer, this is the code:

```
var starList = [];

function Star(){
    this.x = getRandomInt(0, canvas.width);
    this.y = getRandomInt(0, canvas.height);
    this.vx = getRandomInt(2,5);
    this.size = this.vx/5;
    this.opacity = getRandomInt(0, 5000) / 10000;
    this.color = getRandomFromArray(["239, 207, 174", "162, 184, 229", "255, 255, 255"]);
    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+this.color+","+this.opacity+")";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    },
    this.move = function(){
        this.x = this.x - this.vx;

        if(this.x < 0) {
            this.x = canvas.width;
            this.opacity = getRandomInt(0, 5000) / 10000;
            this.color = getRandomFromArray(["239, 207, 174", "162, 184, 229", "255, 255, 255"]);
            this.y = getRandomInt(0, canvas.height);
            this.size = this.vx/5;
            this.vx = getRandomInt(2,5);
        }
    }
}

var canvas, ctx;

function setCanvas(){
    canvas = $('canvas')[0];
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = $(window).width()/5;
    canvas.height = $(window).height()/5;
}

setCanvas();

function generateStars(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
        var star = new Star();
        starList.push(star);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < starList.length; i++) {
        star = starList[i];
        star.draw();
    }
}

generateStars();

function loop() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //draw and move stars
    for(var i = 0; i < starList.length; i++) {
        star = starList[i];
        star.draw();
        star.move();
    }
}
```

I assume using objects for the particles (stars) and looping through the 5000 index array of objects, and executing those two functions is hard on the processor/gpu but how can I optimize this code?

I've seen that others avoid using functions on the constructor, and move and draw the particles when they loop through the array. Will that make it faster?

EDIT: Ignore the getRandomInt and similar functions, they are simple functions I use to generate random stuff.

Comment: Apart from the fact it's an incomplete listing and ideas can't be tested, merely forwarded to you - the obvious point to look seems to be the draw function. 5000 arcs seem likely to take a while to draw. I'd try drawing 5000 rects instead. If that's a lot faster, it may still be worth drawing a round transparent png with composition to colour it. Computing the outline of the arc will be slowish and I'd imagine isn't hardware accelerated. Image blending/scaling/coloring on the other hand can be. Here's something for timing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Answer (score 2):

**The slowest part of your code is the path drawing commands:**

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+this.color+","+this.opacity+")";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Canvas draws very quickly, but 5000 drawings will take some time.

**Instead...**

Create a spritesheet containing all the star variations you want to display.

Copying pixels from the spritesheet to the display canvas is *much faster* than executing drawing commands. This is especially true of drawing arcs where many points must be calculated around the circumference.

*Importantly!*

Limit the star variations -- the viewers won't notice that your stars are not infinitely random.

Then use the clipping version of `drawimage` to quickly draw each desired star-sprite from the spritesheet:

```
// set the global alpha
ctx.globalAlpha = getRandomInt(0, 5000) / 10000;

// cut the desired star-sprite from the spritesheet
// and draw it on the visible canvas
ctx.drawImage( spritesheet,                             // take from the spritesheet
    this.sheetX, this.sheetY, this.width, this.height,  // at this sprite's x,y
    this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)            // and draw sprite to canvas
```

**The spritesheet**

You can use a second in-memory canvas as your spritesheet and create your star-sprites on the client-side when your app first starts up. The `drawImage` command will accept your second in-memory canvas as an image source(!).

```
var spritesheet=document.createElement('canvas');
var spriteContext=spriteSheet.getContext('2d');
...
// draw every variation of your stars on the spritesheet canvas
...
```